# Getting error while dealing with getter and setter in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, getter-setter, getter

I have define the data class as:

```
  data class chatModel(var context:Context?) {

      var chatManger:ChatManager?=null
            //getter
        get() = chatManger
            //setter
        set(value) {
            /* execute setter logic */
            chatManger = value
        }

    }
```

Now how will i access the get() and set() function. 
In java I do like that: 
//for getter

```
new chatModel().getJId()
```

//for setter

```
new chatModel().setJId("jid")
```

**edit:**

As the @yole suggested. I am using setter and getter as:

//set the data

```
var chatDetails:chatModel=chatModel(mApplicationContext)
 chatDetails.chatManger=chatManager
```

But end up getting the  java.lang.StackOverflowError:                                                                               at

```
com.example.itstym.smackchat.Model.chatModel.setChatManger(chatModel.kt:38)
```

line 38 points to

```
chatManger = value
```

this.

@RobCo suggested.

I have change the data class definition as:

```
data class chatModel(var context: Context?) {


    var chatManger:ChatManager

    get() = field
    set(value) {
        field=value
    }
}
```

//set the data.

```
    chatModel(mApplicationContext).chatManger=chatManager
```

//get the data in different activity

```
chatModel(applicationContext).chatManger
```

but getting error property must be initialized. If I assigned it to null then I am getting null not the set value.

Comment: To clarify, are you doing things this way because you want to keep the features that `data class` provides (toString, equals, copy, etc.), but also add custom setter logic?

Comment: yes. I want to use data class for getter and setter also.  @zsmb13

Comment: @zsmb13 I have update my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You call the setter inside of the setter.. a.k.a. infinite loop:

```
    set(value) {
        /* execute setter logic */
        chatManger = value
    }
```

Inside a property getter or setter there is an additional variable available: `field`. This represents the java [backing field](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/properties.html#backing-fields) of that property.

```
    get() = field
    set(value) {
        field = value
    }
```

With a regular var property, these getters and setters are auto-generated.
So, this is default behaviour and you don't have to override getter / setter if all you do is set the value to a field.

Comment: @AnkurKhandelwal "If I assigned it to null then I am getting null not the set value." This is because you create a new instance every time, so the next instance will not have the field set. Try: `val chatModel = chatModel(mApplicationContext); chatModel.chatManger=chatManage; val chatManager = chatModel.chatManager;`. This is about basic instance management and not about custom getters / setters. But please also not my last paragraph: You **don't need** custom getters setters if all they do is set a field.

Comment: then how will I access the set value in the another activity. In the another activity, I have to create the new instance of the chatModel data class. That re-initialize the value to null

Comment: @AnkurKhandelwal This is a different question again: "How to persist objects through activities". You'll probably want a singleton. Kotlin makes this easy with the [object declaration](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/object-declarations.html#object-declarations).

Comment: hmm. I got this. thanks, @RobCo. I got confused with both of them. Thanks a lot. sorry man for troubling you.

Answer (score 1):

It is important to remember that referring to `chatManger` ANYWHERE in the code ends up calling `getChatManger()` or `setChatManger()`, including inside of the getter or setter itself. This means your code will end up in an infinite loop and cause a `StackOverflowError`.

Read up on [Properties](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/properties.html), specifically the section about getters/setters as well as the "backing field".